# How to add separate style in inline code and codeblock in flutter_markdown

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

There are two types of code markdown one is `inline code`(1 backticks) and another is `codeblock` (3 backticks)

```
Markdown(
      controller: scrollController,
      selectable: true,
      builders: {
        'code': CodeElementBuilder()
       },
      styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
        textScaleFactor: 1.0,
        codeblockPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      ),
      data: data,
      styleSheetTheme: MarkdownStyleSheetBaseTheme.material,
   );
```

I create a custom `codeElementBuilder` by using this example [Codeblock Syntax Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592640/how-to-add-code-syntax-highlighter-to-flutter-markdown)

but it also apply to inline code how can I separate both style **inlineCode** and **codeblock**.

I am using [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) package to add markdown

Answer (score 1):

You can add a builder to `pre` instead of `code` and it will apply only to `code blocks`. For example:

```
MarkdownBody(
...
 builders: {
   "pre": CodeBlockMarkdownElementBuilder(),
 },
...
);
```

```
class CodeMarkdownElementBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  ScrollController verticalController = ScrollController();
  ScrollController horizontalController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget visitText(md.Text text, TextStyle? preferredStyle) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
      child: Scrollbar(
        controller: verticalController,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: verticalController,
          child: Scrollbar(
            controller: horizontalController,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: horizontalController,
              child: Text.rich(formatText(preferredStyle, text.text)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working but when we use `visitText(md.Text text ..` we only get text code but I also want to get language  Ex cpp,java at the starting of Element. Which is exist in  `visitElementBefore(md.Element e)` or `visitElementAfter(md.Element e)` but these function not working with `pre` tag.

Comment: yeah, I'm afraid you won't be able to accomplish this without forking the package. Here is where you `pre` custom MarkdownBuilder's `visitText` is called:

https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/6608b604b0e79cc5f99d06dbea12891ff8d65bab/packages/flutter_markdown/lib/src/builder.dart#LL327C8-L327C8

Notice you are calling your custom builder instead of `Scrollbar(...)`. That's the only place you can overwrite `pre` behavior.